# Kick Cash Drawer using Control Code

Tags: c#, thermal-printer, pos-for-.net

I am working with Epson Thermal printer and Cash Drawer. Cash Drawer is connected with the printer. Reference to http://keyhut.com/popopen.htm, the code to kick cash drawer is 27,112,0,50,250. I tried to send this code to printer but nothing happens. I used POS for .NET and the printer is registed in SetupPos.

Here is my code:

```
deviceInfo = posExplorer.GetDevice(DeviceType.PosPrinter, strLogicalName);
m_Printer = (PosPrinter)posExplorer.CreateInstance(deviceInfo);
m_Printer.Open();
m_Printer.Claim(1000);
m_Printer.DeviceEnabled = true;
//command = "ESC|p|0|25|251";
command = "\x1B|\x70|\x00|\x19|\xFB";
m_Printer.PrintImmediate(PrinterStation.Receipt, command);
//m_Printer.CutPaper(100);
m_Printer.DeviceEnabled = false;
m_Printer.Release();
m_Printer.Close();
```

Print text is ok, but send code is not working. What can I do? Thanks.

Comment: Are the pipes in the string needed for the library or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POS for.NET(UnifiedPOS) specification does not support CashDrawer opening by the PrintNormal()/PrintImmediate() method of POSPrinter device.
Since there is a independent CashDrawer device associated with the POSPrinter device, please open() the corresponding device as a CashDrawer and open the drawer with the OpenDrawer() method.

However, depending on the vendor, there is a possibility of supporting usage like you.
I do not have information on whether EPSON POSPrinter supports such usage or not.
Please ask EPSON or your distributor whether or not you can use such a way.

**In addition:**
Instead of POS for.NET, there is a way to install and use a device driver as a regular Windows Printer.
Some vendors offer Windows Printer Driver for receipt printers and also support paper cutting and drawer opening functions.
In EPSON, it is provided under the name Advanced Printer Driver.

The questioner seems to have solved the problem using this.

However, this device driver is often used exclusively with POS for.NET/OPOS/JavaPOS, and when printing, it is necessary to use Windows standard printing API.

Answer (score 0):

The third code from open drawer kick code "ESC|p|0|25|251" to send is actually a symbol to control cash drawer 1 or 2, which is using '0' or '1'. The 0 or 1 symbol in the ASCII table is mapped to decimal 48 or 49. So you need to use the Hex x30 or x31 not x00.
Just to add more info, the forth and the fifth code are the time when the signal kick is ON or OFF by sending decimal (value between 0 to 255) * 2ms.
I hope this solve the problem if you still want to use the cash drawer kick code and attach the device to the printer.